# отличие обобщенного типа с ограничением от интерфейса

Tags: java, kotlin, generics, интерфейс

Есть ли необходимость объявлять обобщенный тип с ограничением, как в Примере1 или лучше в качестве аргумента объявлять сразу интерфейс? Если второй вариант, то, когда применять ограничение, как в первом варианте?

Пример1:

```
class SomeClass<T : SomeInterface>(private var someObject: T) {...}
```

Пример2:

```
class SomeClass(private var someObject: SomeInterface) {...}
```

Comment: лучше для чего ?!

Comment: @keekkenen Я для этого и спрашиваю, т.к не понимаю в каких именно ситуациях следует применять тот или иной способ, если б я знал что для чего лучше, я б здесь не спрашивал!

Answer (score 0):

В ваших коротких примерах не видно разницы.
В обоих случаях передается `SomeInterface` или его потомок.

Разница начнется, как начнете обращаться к `someObject`.
В первом случае он уже будет "правильного" типа, во втором всегда `SomeInterface` и возможно придется кастить под потомка.

Comment: Про котлин мало знаю, но примеры не эквиваленты. Во втором случае явно `someObject` ограничен использованием только типа `SomeInterface` - инвариантность. В первом же `someObject` принимает наследников от `SomeInterface`. Наверное, конструкция `<T : SomeInterface>` по котлиновски должна выглядеть как `<T in SomeInterface>` - ковариантность.